# How can I verify a token from Auth0 in nodejs backend with jwt? JsonWebTokenError

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, auth0

I have a react frontend with auth0 to log users, once a user is logged in I get the token with `getAccessTokenSilently()` and send it to the backend like this:

```
const { user, isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0()

useEffect(() => {
    if (user) getTickets()
}, [user])

async function getTickets() {
    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently()
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/gettickets', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ user, bar }),
    })
    const data = await response.json()
}
```

Once I have the token in my backend I try to verify it jsonwebtoken like this:

```
import express from 'express'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const routerGetTickets = express.Router()

routerGetTickets.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const PUBKEY = process.env.PUBKEY
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1]

    if (token && PUBKEY) {
        jwt.verify(token, PUBKEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, data) => {
            console.log('token :>> ', token)
            if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(403)
                console.log('err :>> ', err)
                return
            } else {
                console.log('everything ok')
            }
        })
    }
})
export default routerGetTickets
```

If I'm not wrong, with algorithm RS256 I have to provide the public key witch I got using openssl with the signin certification I downloaded from my aplication in Auth0 dashboard.

This is the error I get: `err :>>  JsonWebTokenError: secretOrPublicKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256`

And this is my index.ts:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './sass/index.scss'
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)

root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename='/tombola'>
        <Auth0Provider
            domain='*******.uk.auth0.com'
            clientId='*****************************'
            authorizationParams={{
                redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/tombola/callback`,
                audience: 'https://******.uk.auth0.com/api/v2/',
                scope: 'read:current_user update:current_user_metadata'

            }}
        >
            <App />
        </Auth0Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue in the verify jwt method also using Auth0, the problem is with the public key.

You didn't show your .env file where the PUBKEY variable are but I imagine you got it from the Application -> settings -> advanced settings -> certificates, as the Auth0 docs says, but thats the certificate not the pubkey.

To get the public key you need to use the "jwks-rsa" library, it retrieves the publickey using the certificate, getting it from your Auth0 application domain, and for this it needs two things:

1- The domain to construct the url that Auth0 serve the keys.

2- the "kid" header of your jwt token, that identified the correct key.

The code look like this:

```
async function HandleRequest(req, res) {
const cookie = req.headers.cookie;

const token = cookie.split(";")
.find(c => c.trim().startsWith("access_token="))
.split("=")[1]

const kid = decode(token, { complete: true }).header.kid;

const publicKey = (await JwksRsa({
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
    jwksUri: `https://${process.env.DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`
}).getSigningKey(kid)).getPublicKey()

if (cookie && cookie.includes("access_token")) {
    verify(
        token,
        publicKey,
        {
            algorithms: ["RS256"],
        },
        (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(decoded));
            }
        }
    );
} else {
    res.write("No access token found")
}
res.end();
return
}
```

**Note that in the example, I'm in a api route, dealing with a request and getting the jwt token in the headers, my jwt is in the headers as "access_token", yours could be different, then decoding it, extracting the kid identifier, passing it to the jwks-rsa alongside the domain constructed url, and then the jwks-rsa library is dealing with all request to get the certificate from your Auth0 application, and all the cryptography work of retrieving the public key from the certificate.**

You can retrieve from the certificate using "crypto" node module, but I tried and it was a mess because it works bettem with .pem files than with strings, but it's a useful thing to know.

Hope this helps you, I know that Auth0 can mess with our heads while learning.